# Ошибка компиляции скрипта с кириллицей

Tags: nsis

Беру файл из Русскоязычной папки ( `с Англ всё работает` )

```
C:\Users\r3xq1\Desktop\Сборка\FrameworkChanger.exe
```

и он мне возвращает ошибку с таким путём:

> ```
> File: "C:\Users\r3xq1\Desktop\РЎР±РѕСЂРєР°\FrameworkChanger.exe" -> no files found.
> ```

Сразу ясно что не может прочитать кириллицу

---

Пример скрипта `.nsi`

```
OutFile "build.exe"
SilentInstall normal
Section "file0"
SetOutPath "$Desktop"
SetOverwrite on
File "C:\Users\r3xq1\Desktop\Сборка\FrameworkChanger.exe"
SectionEnd
```

Как заставить компилятор читать Русскоязычную директорию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо сохранить файл скрипта в кодировке системы, для русской стандартной является - `cp1251`